# Is it not allowed to make a new thread with the same name even though I already kill one?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, pysimplegui

I made a gui that perform two different jobs with two different intervals with start and stop feature. The goal is to make 2 threads on and off as a user wants. The first start and kill try is just fine, but when I try to make new threads after terminating them it spews an error

Given the following code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import threading
from binance import Client
import time


def make_window(theme=None):
    sg.theme("DarkBlack")

    column = [
        [ sg.Button('do_stuff1_start'), sg.Button("do_stuff1_kill") ],
        [ sg.Button('do_stuff2_start'), sg.Button("do_stuff2_kill") ] ]
    layout = [
        [ sg.T('DCA', font='_ 18', justification='c', expand_x=True) ],
        [ sg.Col(column) ] ]

    window = sg.Window('DCA', layout, finalize=True,
                       keep_on_top=True)
    return window


def do_stuff1(stop_event, arg):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        print("do stuff 1")
        time.sleep(5)
    print("stopped do_stuff1")


def do_stuff2(stop_event, arg):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        print("do stuff 2")
        time.sleep(10)
    print("stopped do_stuff2")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    api_key = "zzz"
    api_secret = "zzz"
    client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

    window = make_window()
    window.finalize()

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break

        elif event == 'do_stuff1_start':
            pill2kill1 = threading.Event()
            do_stuff1 = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff1, args=(pill2kill1, "task1"))
            do_stuff1.start()

        elif event == 'do_stuff2_start':
            pill2kill2 = threading.Event()
            do_stuff2 = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff2, args=(pill2kill2, "task2"))
            do_stuff2.start()

        elif event == 'do_stuff1_kill':
            pill2kill1.set()
            do_stuff1.join()
            print('killed do_stuff1')

        elif event == 'do_stuff2_kill':
            pill2kill2.set()
            do_stuff2.join()
            print('killed do_stuff2')
```

I clicked **do_stuff1_start**, **do_stuff2_start** buttons in my gui and checked them working properly. Then, I clicked **do_stuff1_kill**, **do_stuff2_kill** buttons, also, they worked fine.
The problem is when I click the start buttons again, it spews the below

> Exception in thread Thread-3:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\asd93\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "C:\Users\asd93\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> TypeError: 'Thread' object is not callable

I thought I already completely kill my threads and there is no problem to make them again since there is no living thread with the same name and it is not like "restart" a thread but just making new one on a blank slate.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The PROBLEM is that you have given your thread variable the same name as your function. After you create the first thread, the `do_stuff1` function is deleted.  (OK, it's not literally deleted, because a reference still exists, but you can no longer access it.)  That name now refers to a thread object, and will do so forevermore.  Use a different name.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the answer.I am a noob here so I understood your question but can't think of any approach to change a functions name repeatedly. Could you give me a lead how to avoid the same name for a thread? Any linor post would be highly appreciated. Thank,you in advance

Comment: You don't need to change it repeatedly.  Just don't use the exact same name.  For example, use `do_stuff1_thread = threading.Thread(...)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ahh I just had an epiphany haha. Thank you very much, sir. You made my day. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

The PROBLEM is that you have given your thread variable the same name as your function. After you create the first thread, the do_stuff1 function is deleted. (OK, it's not literally deleted, because a reference still exists, but you can no longer access it.) That name now refers to a thread object, and will do so forevermore. Use a different name.  For example:

```
do_stuff1_thread = threading.Thread( target=do_stuff1, args=(pill2kill, "task1"))
```